# Mysql syntax error in scrapy

Tags: mysql, insert, scrapy

Hi i am working on scrapy and writing a pipeline and in that i had a query which should write the data in to mysql database

```
tx.execute("""INSERT INTO example_table (book_name,price)
                            VALUES (%s,%s)""",   
                                    (item['book_name'],
                                     item['price'],)

                            )
```

I am getting the following errors two errors below

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 2")

(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

I dont know whats wrong in this query but i am unable to save the data in to database.

Can any one have a idea of this.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `%` while executing

```
x.execute("""INSERT INTO example_table (book_name,price)
                            VALUES (%s,%s)""",%   
                                    (item['book_name'],
                                     item['price'])

                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an additional comma at last remove it. following is the correct statement. Kindly try.

```
x.execute("""INSERT INTO example_table (book_name,price)
                            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",   
                                    (item['book_name'],
                                     item['price'])

                            )
```